# How to expose Hive on EMR trough port 443?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, hive, port, amazon-emr

I have AWS EMR and Hive running on it.

I can connect to Hive on port 10000 from outside (from my computer) but need to be able to connect to Hive using Port 443.

How to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: set this env variable in hive-env.sh file `export HIVE_PORT=443`
Most probably the file is in `/etc/hive/conf/hive-env.sh` and *restart hive server*.

Comment: But I think you also need to enable SSL